# Is there any thing like process function in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I was checking source code of a particular package, I came across `new Process()` here in this code

```
  private function runProcess($user, $task) 
  {
    $process = new Process($this->createEnvoyCommand($user)." run $task");

    $process->setTimeout($this->config->get('envoy_timeout'));

    $process->setWorkingDirectory($this->app->make('path.base'));

    $process->run();

    return $process;
   }
```

I want to know if this `process()` really exist and if it work like famous `shell_exec`

Comment: `Process` in this example is a class, not a function. If the code runs in its intended context then presumably yes, the class does exist. You can check the accompanying source code to try and find it, or use an IDE to help you, and/or just try executing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case any want need this...

The Process class executes a command in a sub-process, taking care of the differences between operating system and escaping arguments to prevent security issues. It replaces PHP functions like exec, passthru, shell_exec and system:

[check it out](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)

Comment: This component you've linked to relates to the Symfony framework. But your question is tagged with Laravel. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: @ADyson Laravel already [uses](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/composer.json) bunch of Symfony components. But I agree that it can't be so much clear it is about Laravel from specific code block in question.

Comment: @ADyson Laravel is implementing Symfony Process(), the class is not laravel but Symfony

Comment: @Tpojka interesting, I didn't know that, I've only worked on Laravel stuff once or twice. Thanks.